# Comparing two strings in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the question:

Given two words with the same number of letters in each, work out how many letters need to be changed to get from the first word to the second. A more complex version of edit distance is commonly used in spelling auto-correct algorithms on phones and word processors to find candidate corrections.

The two words should be read from the user with one word per line. For example:

```
Word 1: hello
Word 2: jelly
2
```

this is all I got:

```
w1 = input('Word 1: ')
w2 = input('Word 2: ')
for i in w1:
  for o in w2:
    print(i, o)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
sum(c1 != c2 for c1,c2 in zip(w1,w2))
```

`zip(w1,w2)` creates a generator that returns tuples consisting of corresponding letters of `w1` and `w2`. i.e.:

```
>>> list(zip(w1,w2))
[('h', 'j'), ('e', 'e'), ('l', 'l'), ('l', 'l'), ('o', 'y')]
```

We iterate over these tuples (`c1` gets assigned to each first char and `c2` to each second char) and check if `c1 != c2`. We add up all the instances for which this condition is satisfied to arrive at out answer.

(See [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum))

---

```
>>> w1 = 'hello'
>>> w2 = 'jelly'
>>> 
>>> sum(c1 != c2 for c1,c2 in zip(w1,w2))
2
```

Comment: thank you! It worked! Can you please explain what is happening in the code?

Comment: @Samir Sure, I added some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Using [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html):

```
>>> import difflib
>>> w1, w2 = 'hello', 'jelly'
>>> matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, w1, w2)
>>> m = sum(size for start, end, size in matcher.get_matching_blocks())
>>> n = max(map(len, (w1, w2))) # n = len(w1)
>>> n - m
2
```

Comment: `difflib` is generally a good place to look when solving these types of problems. But for something this simple, it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2):

A functional approach:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> from operator import ne
>>> sum(starmap(ne, zip(word1, word2)))
2
```

Comment: The no import and not using `zip` approach:: `sum(map(str.__ne__, a, b))`

Comment: @JonClements: Nice!  Note that there's a subtle difference, as `zip()` stops after the shortest word, while `map()` goes on until the longest word is exhausted, using `None` as a fill value, in case the words have different lengths.

Comment: True, but I would consider that more desired behaviour as `str.__ne__` will end up with a `TypeError` which is also in effect an assertion that the lengths are equal as stated in the problem text.

Answer (score 1):

If the words are always going to be the same length you can use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to loop through both lists at once:

```
w1 = input('Word 1: ')
w2 = input('Word 2: ')
changes=0    
    for i, o in zip(w1, w2):
    if i != o:
        changes+=1

print "Changes needed: "+str(changes)
```